# Google Custom Site Search and Structured Data meta-tags

Tags: html, meta-tags, google-custom-search

I have implemented Google CSE in a web project and it works properly.
I also need to show an informative label to specify the "section" from which the single result is taken, so I added a meta-tag in page header:

```
<meta name="section" content="Label value..." />
```

Then, I've activated the Structured Data option in the search engine configuration. I'm now getting a link "Structured data" for each result which open an overlay window showing the extra informations (including my section meta-tag).

[Search results list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/653nE.jpg)

[Overlay window screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCT6s.jpg)

I would like to have the value of my "section" meta-tag displayed directly in the results list instead of overlay window. Do you have any idea to get this? Thanks.